# How do triple dots in this C macro body work?

Tags: c, gcc, macros

I've never met `...` in a macro. What is this macro supposed to do? It computes the offset of member from the beginning of type, and then it computes the offset to the end of member field from the beginning of type. But how are these two values combined?

```
#define bpf_ctx_range(TYPE, MEMBER)                     \
offsetof(TYPE, MEMBER) ... offsetofend(TYPE, MEMBER) - 1
```

Comment: It's meant to be used in a `case` statement or a similar construct (it uses GNU C extensions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't *calculate* anything. It is for use in the [case-range](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Case-Ranges.html) extension of GCC, so that you can write:

```
switch (byte_offset) {
case bpf_ctx_range(foo_struct, bar_member):
     // do something...
     break;
}
```

to find out which member the byte at `offset` would belong to.

Answer (score 3):

It's meant to be used in a `case` statement (it uses a GNU C extension, as is common in the Linux kernel).

For example:

```
switch(bpf_var_value)
{
    case bpf_ctx_range(struct bpf_stuff, bpf_member):
        /* do stuff */;
        break;
}
```

It doesn't really calculate anything, it's just a quicker, easier way of writing `case` labels so you don't have to write out each individual value that you want to catch.

However, in this case, it's actually used to do something impossible in strictly conforming C, which is writing multiple `case` labels based on the value of a compile-time constant.

Here's more documentation for the GNU C extension from GCC:

- https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Case-Ranges.html